# DirectProcessor and UnicastProcessor can subscribe to upstream Publisher when they shouldn't. Why?

Tags: spring, reactive-programming, project-reactor

According to the Project Reactor documentation regarding processors:

> direct (DirectProcessor and UnicastProcessor): These processors can
>   only push data through direct user action (calling their Sink's
>   methods directly).
>
> synchronous (EmitterProcessor and ReplayProcessor): These processors
>   can push data both through user action and by subscribing to an
>   upstream Publisher and synchronously draining it.

`UnicastProcessor` shouldn't be able to subscribe to an upstream `Publisher`. There documentation offers an example of the direct user Sink invocation:

```
UnicastProcessor<String> hotSource = UnicastProcessor.create();

Flux<String> hotFlux = hotSource.publish()
                                .autoConnect()
                                .map(String::toUpperCase);

hotFlux.subscribe(d -> System.out.println("Subscriber 1 to Hot Source: "+d));

hotSource.onNext("blue");
```

However I have tried subscribing directly a `UnicastProcessor` to a `Publisher` and it works. This shouldn't be possible as stated in the documentation. Is the doc wrong of am I missing something?

In the following example, I'm subscribing the `UnicastProcessor` to an upstream `Flux` without any problem:

```
    val latch = CountDownLatch(20)

    val numberGenerator: Flux<Long> = counter(1000)
    val processor = UnicastProcessor.create<Long>()

    val connectableFlux = numberGenerator.subscribeWith(processor)

    connectableFlux.subscribe {
        logger.info("Element [{}]", it)
    }

    latch.await()
```

Log:

```
12:50:12.193 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.Map.1 - onSubscribe(FluxMap.MapSubscriber)
12:50:12.196 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.Map.1 - request(unbounded)
12:50:13.203 [parallel-1] INFO reactor.Flux.Map.1 - onNext(0)
12:50:13.203 [parallel-1] INFO com.codependent.Test - Element [0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it seems this aspect of the documentation is outdated. Even `DirectProcessor` can be used as a `Subscriber` and propagate signals to its own subscribers.

NB: You used an `EmitterProcessor` in your snippet, but it still behaves the same with `UnicastProcessor`.